# Modifying array within forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I needed to insert something into an array while being in a middle of Array.forEach. I wanted to check how JavaScript handles those situations. I expected anything, including endless loop. But the result is very strange to me. Can you explain what is going on here:

```js
var A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
A.forEach(function(x) {
   if (x == 3) A.splice(1, 0, 'new')
})
document.write(JSON.stringify(A))
```

Comment: The algorithm for `Array.forEach` is available in [the language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18). (Or to see it in JS check the [polyfill at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From observing with lots of intermediate `writeln`s:

1. The `forEach` loop looks at each *original* index only once -- so it must have stored the length of the array in some temporary variable.
2. The `splice` line inserts "new" at the same place: after the first element.
3. This happens only after seeing the "3" at the 4th position.
4. So at the 3rd iteration, after the first insertion, your array looks like this:

   ```
   [ 0, "new", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
   ```

   and the `forEach` iterator is at element 4 -- which is the "3" again.
5. .. and so "new" gets inserted for the remainders of the *original* array length.

The writer of the `forEach` loop code must have considered someone changing the array behind the scenes. A slightly safer way could have been to make a copy of the original array, but I think that would need a *deep* copy (sich you cannot know in advance how deep the change is going to take place), and that may have led to lots of copying for what seems an edge case.

Answer (score 3):

What you get is the expected behavior and while it's not a true endless loop - it's an unproductive loop.

You are adding an element before the current index. This makes the current value to shift so you will start getting x == 3 on each iteration.

This are all premises for an endless loop however JS forEach puts a ceiling on it, and that ceiling is the number of elements present in your original array. No matter how you manipulate the array, it cannot run for more than 8 times, which is the original length.

The output of this code shows best what is happening:

```
  var A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  A.forEach(function(x, index) {
    document.writeln('A[' + index + '] = ' + x + '<br/>');
    if (x == 3) {
      A.splice(1, 0, 'new')
    }
  })
  document.write(JSON.stringify(A));
```

Output:

```
A[0] = 0
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
A[3] = 3
A[4] = 3
A[5] = 3
A[6] = 3
A[7] = 3
[0,"new","new","new","new","new",1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: _"So you actually end up with an endless loop"_ - No you don't. The algorithm for the `.forEach()` method is explicitly defined to note the original length of the array before looping, and to call the callback for each defined index that is less than that length.

Comment: We're arguing over semantics here. Endless loop can also be defined as an unproductive loop, which is surely the case here. Even a while(true) { } loop is not truly endless because it ends when you run out of memory.

Comment: No, it isn't just semantics. An endless loop is essentially one in which the end condition is never met such it runs "forever" - which may or may not be stopped by the runtime environment rather than literally never ending. `while(true){}` won't run out of memory because additional memory isn't needed on each iteration. The `.forEach()` algorithm's end condition is guaranteed to be met regardless of how you manipulate the array on any given iteration, so it doesn't meet any definition of "endless".

Comment: Your argument won me over and I have updated my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so let's do it by steps:

1. Your loop iterates normally until element "3"
2. On the element "3" your loop past "new" on the first position of your array like:
   [0, new, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], but all your elements are moving on the one position to the right, so on the next iteration of your loop 4th element again "3" because it was moved.
3. He repeats step 2 until the last 8th element, and more 4 times put "new" on the first position of array.
   if you want to paste "new" one time so do it like:

   A.forEach(function(x) {
      if (x == 3) {A.splice(1, 0, 'new'); break;} 
   })